# Vue SPA robots meta tag not indexed by Google

Tags: vue.js, seo, x-robots-tag

For my Vue SPA for which SEO is important; I have written my own function for setting meta tags per route I fire a simple function like this in the `created` lifecycle hook of my views:

```js
document
    .querySelector('meta[name="robots"]')
    .setAttribute('content', 'index');
```

The function seems to work, because when inspecting I see the pages that need to be blocked with a `noindex` value and the pages that need to be indexed with an `index` value.

But Google search console tells me certain pages are not indexed due to the robots meta tag having the value `noindex` (contrary to what I expect and see when inspecting).

Is this an issue with timing and the `created` lifecycle hook maybe?

One of the pages where this issue occurs for extra context:
https://trainervinden.nl/blog/afvallen-met-een-personal-trainer

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Look at your page in google cache, you will see that the tag looks like `<meta name = robots>`. Use the Prerender SPA plugin, it should help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aleksandr! It sounds like quite te rewrite to go and use a prerender plugin though... I am thinking if I could switch to nuxt with similar efforts. Also thinking if there are easier solutions. But probably no short cuts :(

Comment: 1. Setting up the Prerender SPA plugin is much easier than switching to Nuxt.
2. There is another good option - to use Netlify, there is a "Prerendering" option right in the settings (and a bunch of cool things in the form of optimizing and minifying JS, CSS). And it's free and does not require any additional action from you - they will automatically take data from the repository after each commit. Just sign up there, connect the repository, redirect your domain and enjoy.

Comment: Wow thanks for your answers! I will certainly check out my options! Cheers Aleksandr!